# What's the meaning of 'ever'?

Tags: meaning

What’s the meaning of ‘ever’ in this sentence?

“Now, yer mum an’ dad were as good a witch an’ wizard as I ever knew.”

Comment: [Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ever?region=uk&q=ever) Sense 1 ("at any time").

Comment: Hagrid! I miss those books.

Comment: _Ever_ is a suppletive allomorph for the nonexistent phrase _*anywhen_, just as _both_ is a suppletive allomorph for the nonexistent phrase _*all two_. Like _any_, it is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) and may only appear within the scope of a Negative Trigger (like the equative construction _as good ... as `S`_ here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Ever"** means **"in my {life/experience}"**. Hagrid is saying that he's known a lot of witches and wizards, and that Harry Potter's mother and father were first-rate, top level, as good as the best witches and wizards that he has known. He might have said **"Now, I've never known a better witch or wizard than yer mum an’ dad."**